# how can i execute the following code dynamically

Tags: perl

The loop might go up to iteration 10. I mean currently it has five loop, it might go upto 10 loop.
I would like to rewrite the script to simply it.

```
use strict;

my %hashj=(1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0);
my %hashh=(1 => 10, 2 => 18 ,3 => 35, 4 => 40, 5 => 42);

use POSIX;
my $count=ceil(rand(int(4)));
print $count."\n";

if($count==2)
{
    if($hashj{$count-1}==0 && $hashj{$count}==0)
    {
    print $hashh{$count-1} + $hashh{$count},"\n";
    }
}
if($count==3)
{
    if($hashj{$count-2}==0 && $hashj{$count-1}==0 && $hashj{$count}==0)
    {
    print $hashh{$count-2} + $hashh{$count-1} + $hashh{$count},"\n";
    }
}

if($count==4)
{
    if($hashj{$count-3}==0 && $hashj{$count-2}==0 && $hashj{$count-1}==0 && $hashj{$count}==0)
    {
    print $hashh{$count-3} + $hashh{$count-2} + $hashh{$count-1} + $hashh{$count},"\n";
    }
}

if($count==5)
{
    if($hashj{$count-4}==0 && $hashj{$count-3}==0 && $hashj{$count-2}==0 && $hashj{$count-1}==0  && $hashj{$count}==0)
    {
    print $hashh{$count-4} + $hashh{$count-3} + $hashh{$count-2} + $hashh{$count-1} + $hashh{$count},"\n";
    }
}
```

Desired output:
It should be like function, if i set $count value to 5 then it has to generate the following code.

```
if($count==5)
    {
        if($hashj{$count-4}==0 && $hashj{$count-3}==0 && $hashj{$count-2}==0 && $hashj{$count-1}==0  && $hashj{$count}==0)
        {
        print $hashh{$count-4} + $hashh{$count-3} + $hashh{$count-2} + $hashh{$count-1} + $hashh{$count},"\n";
        }
    }
```

Like that i need for $count 1 to 10.

Answer (score 4):

Read up on [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) as well as [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) as these will simplify most of your code.  I would also recommend to **always** `use strict` and `use warnings`, as well as trying for more meaningful variable names.  Here is a simplification of your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw( all sum );

my %hashj = ( 1 =>  0, 2 =>  0, 3 =>  0, 4 =>  0, 5 => 0  );
my %hashh = ( 1 => 10, 2 => 18, 3 => 35, 4 => 40, 5 => 42 );

my @hash_keys = keys %hashj;
my $count = $hash_keys[ int rand scalar @hash_keys ]; # Random element                      
print $count."\n";

check_hashes( \%hashj, \%hashh, $count);  # \%foo is a reference to hash %foo

sub check_hashes {
    my ($hash_1, $hash_2, $count) = @_;
    if ($count < 2) {
        return; # you seem not to care about this case...                                   
    }
    my @indexes = grep { $_ <= $count } keys %$hash_1;  # Dereference a hash reference by putting % in front
    if ( all { $hash_1->{$_} == 0 } @indexes ) {
        my $total = sum map { $hash_2->{$_} } @indexes;
        print $total . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
use strict;
use List::Util qw(sum);

my %hashj=(1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0);
my %hashh=(1 => 10, 2 => 18 ,3 => 35, 4 => 40, 5 => 42);

use POSIX;
my $count=ceil(rand(int(4)));
print $count."\n";

print sum @hashh{1..$count} unless $count<=1 || grep {$_} @hashj{1..$count};
```

- `1..$count` return all numbers between 1 and $count.
- `@hash{ 1, 2, 3 }` = array of values `($hash{1}, $hash{2}, $hash{3})`.
- `grep {$_}` for array return all non zero elements. In scalar context (and boolean context of `unless`) - return number all non zero elements.
- function `sum()` from List::util package return sum of array elements

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if we can get this right together

The start of your code looks good

```
use strict;
my %hashj=(1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 0, 4 => 0, 5 => 0);
my %hashh=(1 => 10, 2 => 18 ,3 => 35, 4 => 40, 5 => 42);
use POSIX;
my $count=ceil(rand(int(4)));
print $count."\n";
```

and now the missing 3 lines:

```
if (is_0_hash($count, %hashj)) {
   print sum_hash($count, %hashh);
}
```

the 2 helper subs at the end;:

```
sub is_0_hash {
   my ($count, %hash) = @_;
   foreach my $i ( 1 .. $count) {
       if ($hash{$i} != 0) {
         return #false
       }
   }
   return 1;
}

sub sum_hash {
   my ($count, %hash) = @_;
   my $sum = 0;
   foreach my $i ( 1 .. $count) {
       $sum += $hash{$i};
   }
   return $sum;
}
```

HTH
Georg